# Is it a bad idea to reload routes dynamically in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an application I'm writing where I'm allowing the administrators to add aliases for pages, categories, etc, and I would like to use a different controller/action depending on the alias (without redirecting, and I've found that render doesn't actually call the method. I just renders the template). I have tried a catch all route, but I'm not crazy about causing and catching a DoubleRender exception that gets thrown everytime.

The solution for this I've come up with is dynamically generated routes when the server is started, and using callbacks from the Alias model to reload routes when an alias is created/updated/destroyed. 
Here is the code from my routes.rb:

```
Alias.find(:all).each do |alias_to_add|
    map.connect alias_to_add.name, 
            :controller => alias_to_add.page_type.controller, 
            :action => alias_to_add.page_type.action,
            :navigation_node_id => alias_to_add.navigation_node.id
end
```

I am using callbacks in my Alias model as follows:

```
after_save :rebuild_routes
after_destroy :rebuild_routes

def rebuild_routes
    ActionController::Routing::Routes.reload!
end
```

Is this against Rails best practices? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more and perhaps post an example of what your aliasing is supposed to do (and maybe a bit out of your routes.rb file)? I don't quite understand it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick Solution

Have a catch-all route at the bottom of routes.rb.  Implement any alias lookup logic you want in the action that route routes you to.

In my implementation, I have a table which maps defined URLs to a controller, action, and parameter hash.  I just pluck them out of the database, then call the appropriate action and then try to render the default template for the action.  If the action already rendered something, that throws a DoubleRenderError, which I catch and ignore.

You can extend this technique to be as complicated as you want, although as it gets more complicated it makes more sense to implement it by tweaking either your routes or the Rails default routing logic rather than by essentially reimplementing all the routing logic yourself.

If you don't find an alias, you can throw the 404 or 500 error as you deem appropriate.

### **Stuff to keep in mind:**

**Caching:** Not knowing your URLs a priori can make page caching an absolute bear.  Remember, it caches based on the URI supplied, NOT on the `url_for (:action_you_actually_executed`).  This means that if you alias

```
/foo_action/bar_method
```

to

```
/some-wonderful-alias
```

you'll get some-wonderful-alias.html living in your cache directory.  And when you try to sweep foo's bar, you won't sweep that file unless you specify it explicitly.

**Fault Tolerance:** Check to make sure someone doesn't accidentally alias over an existing route.  You can do this trivially by forcing all aliases into a "directory" which is known to not otherwise be routable (in which case, the alias being textually unique is enough to make sure they never collide), but that isn't a maximally desirable solution for a few of the applications I can think of of this.

Answer (score 11):

Ben,

I find the method you're already using to be the best. Using Rails 3, you'd have to change the code a bit, to:

```
MyNewApplication::Application.reload_routes!
```

That's all.

Comment: `Rails.application.reload_routes!` likewise works and doesn't require you to use the name of your application (useful for me, building a template application).

Comment: Just a word of caution: I believe if you are running multiple processes (like on Heroku) you would have to run this on each process, so if you call this in an after_create or after_destroy hook, other processes will not have their routes reloaded.

Answer (score 2):

First, as other have suggested, create a catch-all route at the bottom of routes.rb:

```
map.connect ':name', :controller => 'aliases', :action => 'show'
```

Then, in AliasesController, you can use render_component to render the aliased action:

```
class AliasesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if alias = Alias.find_by_name(params[:name])
      render_component(:controller => alias.page_type.controller, 
                        :action => alias.page_type.action,
                        :navigation_node_id => alias.navigation_node.id)
    else
      render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: According to http://rubyonrails.org/deprecation, components have been deprecated. I'd rather not using something which could disappear in a future version of Rails.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you could use `method_missing` in your controllers and then lookup the alias, maybe like this:

```
class MyController
  def method_missing(sym, *args)
    aliased = Alias.find_by_action_name(sym)
    # sanity check here in case no alias

    self.send( aliased.real_action_name )
    # sanity check here in case the real action calls a different render explicitly
    render :action => aliased.real_action_name
  end

  def normal_action
    @thing = Things.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

If you wanted to optimize that, you could put a `define_method` in the `method_missing`, so it would only be 'missing' on the first invocation, and would be a normal method from then on.