# Ruby On Rails Updating Heroku Dynamic Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, routes

I've got an app which uses app-wide slugs (uses [Slugalicious gem](https://github.com/RISCfuture/slugalicious) with Sluggable table), and have routed to these slugs by using this code:

```
  #Slugs
  begin  
      Slug.all.each do |s|
        begin
          get "#{s.slug}" => "#{s.sluggable_type.downcase.pluralize}#show", :id => s.slug
        rescue
        end
      end
  rescue
  end
```

I currently update the routes when I update the slugs model with this code:

```
after_save :update_routes

def update_routes
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
end
```

This works perfectly in dev:

[image: Routes Work Well In Dev]

The problem I'm getting is that if I update or create a new slug, Heroku doesn't update to accommodate it. It works in development, and (confusingly), it works if I do "heroku run rake routes" on Heroku. But the app just shows a 404 if I try to browse to the new URL. If I redeploy the app, all the routes work, which leads me to believe it's something to do with updating the routes app-wide

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129510/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-reload-routes-dynamically-in-rails) said it's something to do with running multiple processes on Heroku, but I've yet to find this.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason you don't have a single `/:slug` route and some conflict checking to keep slugs from matching application routes?

Comment: Thanks for the question. What happens is that the slugs are all for specific pieces of content, and considering I have a separate admin area & the slugs are created by a single entity, I figured that I could keep on top of the routes myself. To be honest, I've not experienced that problem yet, so I've not had to write a fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it!

There is something called an "**[ActiveRecord Observer](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Observer)**" which have been depreciated since Rails 4.0. I found [this website](http://eveloverails.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/create-multiple-routes-on-ruby/) which explained what I wanted to do, but it was slightly outdated. I've included by code for rails 4.0 below:

If you're using Rails 4, use the [rails-observers gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers)

**Add the call to your environment files**:

```
#config/application.rb (can be placed into dev or prod files if required)
config.active_record.observers = :slug_observer
```

**Add a new observer class** into your models folder:

```
#app/models/slug_observer.rb
class SlugObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(slug)
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
    slug.logger.info("Routes Reloaded")
  end

  def after_destroy(slug)
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
    slug.logger.info("Routes Reloaded")
  end
end
```

The way this works is to call these bolt-on functions once the original has been run. This allowed my app to operate the function indepenent of the model in question, thus updating the routes correctly.