# How to add a method to an activerecord collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to add a method to all collections for a specific model. Let's say I want to add the method `my_complicated_averaging_method` to the WeatherData collections:

```
WeatherData.all.limit(3).my_complicated_averaging_method()
Station.first.weatherdata.my_complicated_averaging_method()
```

What is the best way to do this? At the moment the only way I've found is like this:

```
class WeatherData < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_complicated_averaging_method
    weighted_average = 0
    @relation.each do |post|
      # do something complicated
      # weighted_average = 
    end
    return weighted_average
  end
end
```

Is this a good way for adding a method to a collection? Is there a better / supported way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There a lot of ways how to do it, and Yours is completely valid (though I personally prefer to wrap class methods into separate block check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505067/class-self-idiom-in-ruby) out ), but as people are adding more business logic to their models and blindly follow "skinny controllers, fat models" concept, models turn into complete mess.

To avoid this mess it's a good idea to introduce service objects, in Your case it would be like this:

```
class AverageWeatherData
  class << self
    def data(collection)
      new(collection).data
    end
  end

  def initialize(collection)
    @collection = collection
  end

  def data
    @collection.reduce do |avg, post|
      # reduce goes through every post, each next iteration receives in avg a value of the last line of iteration
      # do something with avg and post 
    end
    # no need for explicit return, every line of Ruby code returns it's value
    # so this method would return result of the reduce
    # more on reduce: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce
  end
end
```

Now You can call this class directly by passing Your collection to it. But You can also proxy the call like this:

```
def self.my_complicated_averaging_method
  AverageWeatherData.data(@relation)
end
```

I encourage You to lear more of this approach by reading this blog:
http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

**UPD**

You are right using instance variable is a possible way to mess up object internals(plus it's not a public interface and it might change in future). My proposal here is to use method `scoped`. Basically replace `@relation` with `scoped`.

Check this example. I have used a model from my own project to show that it actually works

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > Tracking # just asking console to load this class before modifying it
# => Tracking(id: integer, action: string, cookie_id: string, ext_object_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
2.0.0p247 :002 > class Tracking
2.0.0p247 :003?>     def self.fetch_ids
2.0.0p247 :004?>         scoped.map(&:id)
2.0.0p247 :005?>       end
2.0.0p247 :006?>   end
# => nil
2.0.0p247 :007 >
2.0.0p247 :008 >   Tracking.where(id: (1..100)).fetch_ids
#  Tracking Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "trackings".* FROM "trackings" WHERE ("trackings"."id" BETWEEN 1 AND 100)
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

**UPD**

In Rails 4 `scoped` is deprecated, so it's correct to use `all`.

```
all.map(&:id)
```

Comment: My question was bad :( I was really looking into if "@relation" was good to use or if there was a better way for adding methods to a collection. I really like your post though.

Comment: It gives me an error with rails 4 but I found the problem: https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure/pull/73

Thanks for the help and the link to the great blog post from codeclimate!

Comment: My bad. scoped is deprecated in Rails 4, now You need to use `all`. It looks a bit odd, but it I just checked it and it works.

Comment: __UPD2__ Do not `.map(&:id)` on collections, `.pluck(:id)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

On Rails >= 4 you can to use `where(nil)` inplace of `scoped`

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base  
  def self.bar
    where(nil).pluck(:id)
  end
end

Foo.where(id: [1, 2, 3]).order(:id).bar
```

And further, you can use `#scope`, for example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :bar, -> {where(nil).pluck(:id)}
end
```

Finally, You can write code like `Foo.all.bar`

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to get things working, but for more finesse I'm sure there is something much better. Admittedly, you weren't too specific in describing what you wanted to achieve with this, so I can only give you this broad suggestion

You may want to look into "**[Observer Classes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Observer)**"

---

I wrote a post about them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144071/ruby-on-rails-updating-heroku-dynamic-routes/19145880#19145880)

> Observer Classes basically monitor a particular model function & extend it. I think they're only for the before_filter, etc functions, but I don't see why you can't extend indvidual functions that you create

You'll have to use [the `rails-observers` gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers) in rails 4.0+ to get them working, as they've been depreciated from the rails core