# Model column that depends on other columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a gamification app that has four types of points, and the sum of all these kinds is the total points for a user, I want to be able to do `sum` and `scope`s on that column, so I think I should have it as a column in the DB.

```
scope :points_rank, -> { order(points: :desc) }
```

I was using a `before_save` for adding all four `point` types and storing it in `points`, but now I'm using a gem that does `increment` to these types of points, so when it updates those values, the `before_save` is not called, hence not updating the `points` value as expected.

What is the correct ActiveRecord *callback* to be using instead of `before_save`, or what else could I be doing to keep the column updated.

Comment: Can you please share the name of the gem. I think you should look for the gem documentation for callbacks.

Comment: Sure, its [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture)

Comment: `counter_culture will only update its counters in the after_commit callback`. So I think you should try to `after_commit`

Comment: @AmitPatel, it didn't work either, I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `after_touch` callback instead.

`after_touch` callback is triggered whenever an object is touched.

So, whenever point type changes, it should update the `points`.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, any other idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `counter_culture` seems to be a way to enhance the [counter_cache](http://yerb.net/blog/2014/03/13/three-easy-steps-to-using-counter-caches-in-rails/) functionality of rails...

> Used to cache the number of belonging objects on associations. For example, a `comments_count` column in a `Post` class that has many instances of `Comment` will cache the number of existent comments for each post.

<s>It *might not* be exactly what you want, judging from your question.</s>

Okay I get it. You're using *points* in your `User` model to create a "cached" column which can be used for wider application functionality. Okay that's cool...

--

Your setup, then, will look something *like* this (you were manually setting the `counter_cache` column, and now the gem handles it):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   counter_cache :points
end

#app/models/point.rb
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end
```

The question is then that when you update the *points* model, you need to be able to update the "cached" column in the *users* model, now without any callbacks.

---

> What is the correct ActiveRecord callback to be using instead of before_save

I'm presuming you're calling *before_save* on your `User` model (IE adding the associated data and putting the *points* column?

If so, you should try using a callback on the `Point` model, perhaps something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :points
end

#app/models/point.rb
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :points
   after_commit :update_user

   private

   def update_user
      if user?
          user.update(points: x + y + z)
      end
   end
end
```

--

**Oberservers**

If you have real problems, you *could* look at [**ActiveRecord observers**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Observer).

Here's an answer I wrote about it: [Ruby On Rails Updating Heroku Dynamic Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144071/ruby-on-rails-updating-heroku-dynamic-routes)

Whether this will trigger without any callbacks is another matter, but what I *can* say is that it will work to give you functionality you may not have had access to otherwise:

```
#config/application.rb (can be placed into dev or prod files if required)
config.active_record.observers = :point_observer

#app/models/point_observer.rb
class PointObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def before_save(point)
    #logic here
  end
end
```

A good way to test this would be to use it (you'll have to use the [rails-observers gem](https://github.com/rails/rails-observers)) with different methods. IE:

```
 #app/models/point_observer.rb
class PointObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def initialize(point)
     #if this fires, happy days
  end
end
```