# Where should I put MyApplication::Application.reload_routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

In Rails 4 application I need to reload routes (routes.rb) for every request before the   application uses it. Where should I put `MyApplication::Application.reload_routes!`
I have tried to put it in `config/applicaion.rb,config/environments.rb` but it's not working.
I have also tried to put it in `before_filter` of ApplicationController and it's also failing. 
[RoR api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) is brief on how to  use it.
So any assistance/guidance on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The routes are dynamic

Comment: I doubt that is possible. But i also doubt that routes must be dynamic. Code should be dynamic, route can be the same. Could you plz specify the concrete usecase

Comment: For instance if you have your controllers stored in a table in a database.For every request you have to query from the table for specific controller depending on url parameter(s).Yes routes must not be dynamic but can be dynamic. See this [link](http://archive.gibberishcode.net/archives/creating-dynamic-routes-at-runtime-in-rails-4/130)

Answer (score 1):

Seriuosly i would never do that. It is massive intervention into Rails internals. Just configure one dynamic route to a single controller. Then load some Command(Service) 
according to the dynamic part of the url from the db, deserialize, instantiate and pass
the current controller as a reference to this dynamic service constructor.

The dynamic service you are loading should be implemented according to the following refactoring technique:

[Replace Method with Method Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-method-with-method-object)

Another Option would be to load a lambda/Proc because it would automatically have the controller scope once instantiated

Comment: I am trying out your answer.However I need a straight forward answer for the question. Is it possible to reload routes ( routes.rb) just after a request (Yes or No ?).If your answer is Yes show me an example and if your answer is No then in what circumstances would you reload routes(routes.rb) for RoR application.

Comment: Yes, you can reload routes after a request and have new routes on the following request. However in question you've asked `for every request before the application uses it`, which is not possible. You could reload the routes, then redirect immediatly to the new route, but this would be 2 requests. I would only reload the routes if the are some sort of configurable by the admin at well defined periods. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129510/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-reload-routes-dynamically-in-rails

Comment: In order to provide you an example, you have to create a new question, describing the concrete problem. I bet, there is a solution without reloading the routes on each request